# Chromium Embedded Framework VS2013 strings error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, chromium-embedded, visual-studio-2010

I am converting a project which uses CEF, from VS2010 Express to VS2013 Express. I recompiled libcef_d.lib and libcef_dll_wrapper_d.lib with VS2013 just fine. But now I have problems when I try to link the libs in my main project. How can I resolve this?

```
WebBrowser_Handler.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cef_string_utf16_clear
WebBrowserManager.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cef_string_utf16_clear
libcef_dll_wrapper_d.lib(browser_ctocpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__cef_string_list_alloc
libcef_dll_wrapper_d.lib(cookie_manager_ctocpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__cef_string_list_alloc
libcef_dll_wrapper_d.lib(drag_data_ctocpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__cef_string_list_alloc
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that libcef_dll_wrapper uses the same runtime library as your project: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx.

Second, if you build CEF from source code and you'd changed something in CEF include folder, you need to run the translator tool:

```
cd x:\path\to\cef\tool
translator.bat
```

Comment: I use the same runtime and i have not change the CEF include folder.

Comment: What version of CEF you are trying to use? Did you build libcef or you downloaded it from cefbuilds.com?

Comment: I downloaded cef_binary_1.1364.1123_windows.zip from http://www.magpcss.net/cef_downloads/